# DateTime precision in .NET core

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core

Following Eric Lippert's [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime/) years back on precision of `DateTime`, I ran his test on .netcore and .NET Framework 4.5.2, on the same machine with Windows 10.

```
        var n = 1000;
        int i = 0;
        long[] diffs = new long[n];
        while (i++ < n-1)
        {
            if (ticks != DateTime.Now.Ticks)
            {
                var newTicks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
                var diff = newTicks - ticks;
                diffs[i] = diff;
                ticks = newTicks;
            }
        }
        foreach (var d in diffs)
        {
            if (d == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("same");
            else
                Console.WriteLine(d);

        }
```

The result on .NET framework 4.5.2 was as expected: some random "same" in output which means `DateTime` is not precise to some sub-levels.

However, the result on .NET core was totally different: no "same" in output. Not two `Ticks` had the same value.

What would be the explanation?

Comment: Can you more precisely lay down what type of explanation you expect? It says right in the article that ... _Different flavours of Windows might give you different results, depending on_ ... Same goes for different flavours of library, framework, os, hardware and all things working "below" your code.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/9736

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that on any computer any representation of a date/time variable must be "not percise to some sub-levels".

Comment: It's also worth noting that you're using `DateTime.Now` rather than `DateTime.UtcNow`, which means that every call needs to do a time zone conversion. That takes time, making it less likely that you'll see the same value twice. You may well find that if you use `DateTime.UtcNow` you'll get a different result.

Comment: (And likewise, writing a value to the console takes time. To get the best chance of seeing the same value multiple times, you want to make the inner loop as tight as possible. For example, you might want to pre-allocate a `DateTime[]` with 1000 elements, then write a loop that *just* populates that array... then analyze it afterwards.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your feedback. I updated the question. The output is now different, on `.NET Framework` I get the same tick all the time, on `.NET Core` the deltas are now much smaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The explanation would be, that dot net asks the underlying operating system for the current time. The operating system asks the underlying hardware. In ancient times the hardware clock (RTC) on the motherboard used to update itself once in about 15 milli seconds.
That number was derived from the 60Hz AC line frequency in US which the power grid maintained sufficient accurately. Remember those were the days of "slow" computers and designers tried to squeeze in every bit of performance they could. So the OS did not consult RTC everytime someone asked for time and passed a cached copy of the value - which is updated very infrequently.

Somewhere down the line, the motherboard evolved and the RTCs became more precise. But the OS and all the things on top of it did not feel the need for it. Remember h/w evolved far faster than software and even till day, consumer grade software waste a large fraction of raw h/w capability. So when dot net framework asked OS for time, it got back the imprecise data even when the h/w was capable. The accuracy did evolve from 15ms to below 1ms, but that was it.

Come windows 8 (server 2012), it was finally realized that (1) applications could do better with more precise time (2) computers are fast so consulting RTC everytime is no longer a problem (3) a large population of programmers and programs are used to and actually rely on the imprecise time behavior. So they (win 8)  went on to introduce a new marginally slower mechanism to obtain the most precise time data, but left the original implementation unchanged.

Dot net had always used the older and imprecise OS function `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` and when a new cousin `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` appeared in win 8, dot net chose to go the backward compatible way and did nothing.

Dot net core is a fresh rewrite of many core features and now leverages the high precision data source.

## Edit

If the current time is *13:14:15:123456* , there is still no guarantee that the real true time, as seen by the physicists and astronomers is that. Your computer is not an atomic clock. And certainly not a well synchronized clock. The only thing it means is that if two events happened at different timestamps then one event happened certainly before the another. In older computers, rate of generation of events (ex logs, files, database txns etc) was lower and so there was low chance that sequential events would be assigned same timestamps. This new time system caters to modern high rate activities so that you can mark sequential events as different. Still for two very close events, there will always be a chance of same timestamp. That is eventually unavoidable. If you need nanosecond level measurement (why) you need different tools like `Stopwatch` and not `System.DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks. So in this case, is the precision of new `DateTime` correct and reliable or from some nth second onward it's garbage? For example if the current time is _13:14:15:123456_, can we rely on it to the last part?

Comment: @Hans, please see edited answer. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: I see! It could be another question, but what was the rationale behinde making `DateTime` more precise while by nature it cannot be more precise than milliseconds?

Comment: @Hans in reality most computers only synchronize their clocks every seven days, and the accuracy of the internal clocks used means that they have usually gained or lost a couple of seconds in that time. As Inquisitive said, the clock serves two purposes, one is to give an approximate actual time, and the other is to determine what order things happened on the computer. For this reason the OS clocks go to some effort to be "monotonic" so that the clock time doesn't go backwards, even if this means the time is slightly wrong.