# C# DateTime.Now difference between net48 and net5

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-4.8

Kinda want to know the reason why the result of DateTime.Now between net48 & net5 is different
For whatever reason, the DateTime.Now result in net48 is always the same in 1000 run. That doesn't seems possible. The DateTime.Now from net5 seems more realistic. Either the result is being cached in compile time or the performance of net48 DateTime.Now is so much better than net5 one ?

Hope someone can point out the root cause.

Thanks

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_Dummy()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var now1 = DateTime.Now;
            var now2 = DateTime.Now;
            var diffMs = (now1 - now2).TotalMilliseconds;
            Assert.IsTrue(Math.Abs(diffMs) < 300);
            Console.WriteLine($"diff: {diffMs} now1: {now1.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds} now2: {now2.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds}");
        }
    }
```

.Net Framework 4.8 result (all the same for 1000 run)

```
diff: 0 now1: 52820303.6843 now2: 52820303.6843
diff: 0 now1: 52820303.6843 now2: 52820303.6843
diff: 0 now1: 52820303.6843 now2: 52820303.6843
```

.Net 5

```
diff: -0.0015 now1: 52819332.5248 now2: 52819332.5263
diff: -0.0242 now1: 52819332.7427 now2: 52819332.7669
diff: -0.0007 now1: 52819332.7973 now2: 52819332.798
diff: -0.0002 now1: 52819332.8006 now2: 52819332.8008
diff: -0.0001 now1: 52819332.8025 now2: 52819332.8026
diff: -0.0001 now1: 52819332.8041 now2: 52819332.8042
diff: -0.0002 now1: 52819332.8057 now2: 52819332.8059
diff: -0.0002 now1: 52819332.8073 now2: 52819332.8075
diff: -0.0001 now1: 52819332.8149 now2: 52819332.815
diff: -0.0001 now1: 52819332.8169 now2: 52819332.817
diff: -0.0001 now1: 52819332.8185 now2: 52819332.8186
diff: -0.0001 now1: 52819332.8201 now2: 52819332.8202
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime precision in .NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688977/datetime-precision-in-net-core)

Comment: what about DateTime.UtcNow? Seems like a bug for me, but could be intended caching for heavy time conversion to locale.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thanks for pointing that out. It looks like the answer I want. So, it means my question is duplicated. Sigh ... i did review all the suggested possible similar question and couldn't find anything. Thanks a lot

Comment: why sigh? it was a valid question, and you got an answer. everything seems like it should be ;) (and i had to use quite a bit of google-fu)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I do believe double checking if the question is duplicated is everyone's responsibilties in order to avoid wasting everyone's time. that's the reason of my sigh. Anyway. Great answer !